Locking resource in FastAPI - using a multiprocessing Worker
I would like to make an FastAPI service with one /get endpoint which will return a ML-model inference result. It is pretty easy to implement that, but the catch is I periodically need to update the model with a newer version (trough request on another server with models, but that is beside the point), and here I see a problem!
What will happen if one request calls old model, but the old model is currently being replaced by a newer one?? How can I implement this kind of locking mechanism with asyncio ?
Here is the code:
import asyncio
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

app = FastAPI()
sbertmodel = None


def create_model():
    global sbertmodel
    sbertmodel = SentenceTransformer('multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1')


# if you try to run all predicts concurrently, it will result in CPU trashing.
pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1, initializer=create_model)


def model_predict():
    ts = time.time()
    vector = sbertmodel.encode('How big is London')
    return vector


async def vector_search(vector):
    # simulate I/O call (e.g. Vector Similarity Search using a VectorDB)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.005)


@app.get("/")
async def entrypoint(request: Request):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ts = time.time()
    # worker should be initialized outside endpoint to avoid cold start
    vector = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, model_predict)
    print(f"Model  : {int((time.time() - ts) * 1000)}ms")
    ts = time.time()
    await vector_search(vector)
    print(f"io task: {int((time.time() - ts) * 1000)}ms")
    return "ok"

My model update would be implemented trough Repeated tasks (but that is not important now) : https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/repeated-tasks/
This is the idea of a model serving : https://luis-sena.medium.com/how-to-optimize-fastapi-for-ml-model-serving-6f75fb9e040d
EDIT: what is important to run multiple requests concurrently, and while model is updating, acquire lock so that requests wouldnt fail, they should just wait a little bit longer because it is a small model.

Did you try asyncio.Lock?

It would depend on how you're currently accessing the model, but a common way to handle updating resources while running is to not replace the original reference before you've loaded and processed everything - so if you have a dependency or global state in your application, don't replace that part before you've loaded the new resource - serve the old one until the new one is ready. If you need locking you might also need it to be cross process (i.e. multiple workers), so you might want to look at something like redis (or compatible) to create a cross process lock.

@MatsLindh if my API is online, it is constantly serving models, I need to implement some sort of background task that will lock the current resource, and replace it with the old one. I thought of only doing locking when the model has finished downloading. Then I would need to somehow acquire lock (models are small) on a function that serves model. I just dont know what will happen if multiple requests are wanting to access the model while updating ??

In the example you've linked, replacing the sbertmodel variable with an updated model shouldn't cause any issues, since there is only a single call to the model - you're either calling it or not, and there is no subsequent calls where two different variables can be used - so in that case, no locking should be necessary (which is why I said it depends on your current code). If you have multiple calls, you can assign the reference to your own variable that won't get replaced while you're calling the model (or use a dependency) (i.e. copy it over from the old one).

"since there is only a single call to the model" Sorry I dont understand that. I blog there is ProcessPoolExecutor invoked and that enables (from what I can see) a multiple request concurrently access the model. Lets say there are 10 coroutines wanting to access the model, and one coroutine wants to update it, what will happen ??? I was thinking I need to implement read-write lock. THe update method should have a write lock.... Tnx for response btw

It is possible to give a straigfrward answer, with code, if there is code in your question, with a minimal reproducible example. A 20-30 line py file with the setup for the model, the replacing model endpoint, and a common endpoitn that will make use of the model. With that in place, I, or other person could add a couple lines to your example showing how to add an asyncio.Lock (if it is needed at all).
Without code, the answer is "you could, maybe, use an asyncio.Lock" is as a complete thing as you will get. Sorry.

Thanks for your snippet.
With it visible, it is possible to write a proposal
for what you need there - as it turns out, you need to update
the model in a subprocess, and there is nothing to worry about in the main-process async part of the code. Signaling
the worker processes for the updates, though, needs some attention.
Since you are using ProcessPool workers,
you need a way to expose variables from the
root process that the process workers can "see" -
Python has this in the form of
multiprocessing.Manager objects -
Bellow i pick your code and add the parts
needed for your requisites of "no imediate, but no conflicting"
updatding of the model in use.
As it turns out, once we have variables that can be seen in the
worker, all that is needed is a check in the model-runner
method itself to see if the model needs to be  updated.\
I didn't run this snippet - so there might be some typo in variable names or even one or other missing parenthesis - use as a model,
not "copy + paste" (but I tested the "moving parts"
of Manager.Namespace() objects and passing then as parameters
as initargs in a ProcessPoolExecutor)
import asyncio
import time
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Manager


from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

sbertmodel = None
local_model_iteration = -1
shared_namespace = None

# pool, and other multi-processing objects can`t simply
# be started in the top level of the body, or they't be re
# created in each subprocess!!
# check https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#lifespan


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    global pool, root_namespace
    manager = Manager()

    root_namespace = manager.NameSpace()
    
    # Values assigned to the "namespace" object are 
    # visible on the subprocess created by the pool
    
    root_namspace.model_iteration = 0
    root_namespace.model_parameters = "multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1"
    
    # (as long as we send the namespace object to each subprocess
    # and store it there)
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1, initializer=initialize_subprocess, initargs=(root_namespace,))
    with pool, manager:
        # pass control to fastapi: all the app is executed
        yield
    # end of "with" block:
    # both the pool and manager are shutdown when fastapi server exits!
    

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

# if you try to run all predicts concurrently, it will result in CPU trashing.


def initialize_subprocess(shared_namespace_arg):
    global shared_namespace
    # Store the shared namespace in _this_ process:
    shared_namespace = shared_namespac_arg
    update_model()
    
def update_model():
    "called on worker subprocess start, and at any time the model is outdated" 
    global local_model_iteration, sbertmodel
    local_model_iteration = shared_namespace.model_iteration
    # retrieve parameter posted by root process:
    sbertmodel = SentenceTransformer(shared_namespace.model_parameters)



def model_predict():
    ts = time.time()
    # verify if model was updatd from the root process
    if shared_namespace.model_iteration > local_model_iteration:
        # if so, just update the model
        update_model()
    # model is synchronied, just do our job:
    vector = sbertmodel.encode('How big is London')
    return vector


async def vector_search(vector):
    # simulate I/O call (e.g. Vector Similarity Search using a VectorDB)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.005)


@app.get("/")
async def entrypoint(request: Request):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ts = time.time()
    # worker should be initialized outside endpoint to avoid cold start
    vector = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, model_predict)
    print(f"Model  : {int((time.time() - ts) * 1000)}ms")
    ts = time.time()
    await vector_search(vector)
    print(f"io task: {int((time.time() - ts) * 1000)}ms")
    return "ok"

@app.get("/update_model")
async def update_model_endpoint(request: Request):
    # extract from the request the needed paramters for the new model
    ...
    new_model_parameters = ...
    # uodate the model parameters and model iteration so they are visible
    # in the worker(s)
    root_namespace.model_parameters = new_model_parameters
    # This increment taking place _after_ the "model_parameters" are set 
    # is all that is needed to keep things running in order here:
    root_namespace.model_iteration += 1
    return {} # whatever response needed by the endpoint
    
    





Tnx for the answer, but I didnt get one thing. If I want to implement a "repeated-task" (https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/repeated-tasks/)  that will fetch every X hours a new model, and serve that as a new model, can I replace your "/update_model" endpoint with "repeated-task()" ? Because the entire model file must be changed/replaced with a newer one. So If "/" endpoint is reading that file, a new update must replace that file, so the point is to not have any resource deadlocks

yes, of course - as you didn't mention what would trigger the model change, I just added an example as an endpoint  - it can be trigered in anyway - i- he only important thing is to update the cross-process visible variables, as this method does.

So if a model is downloaded trough this "repeated-task", it would be represented as a file (lets call it "model-new"). While model is downloading, concurrent requests are being made on a "old-model" which is loaded on api.  So when I update model, I want "model-new" to be used, and the old one to be deleted. But I think that would be a problem because maybe maybe other older requests are still trying to access "old-model" (I dont know if this is a possibility). Is there any way to ensure that model can be deleted only if it is not accessed ?

in the way it is in this code, for example, there is no problem. The old-model is loaded into the "sbertmodel"  global variable for each worker - it will complete its task, and when a new task is started, it verifies for a new model before anything, updates the model in memory, and there are no references left of the older model.
Now, even if each subprocess had background tasks working with the models when a new model is started, all they´d need would be to have a reference to the model in a local variable - so even for far more complicated cases, the plan above would work with ease.

Is it possible to avoid global variables in "initialize_subprocess()" and "update_model()" ? Something like this comes to mind : https://github.com/fastapi/fastapi/issues/592#issuecomment-538764818

the global variables are object references which have to exist in a single place in a process. You can use whatever mechanism you want for those - there could be a class used as namespace, or a contextvars.ContextVar variable, a types.SimpleNameSpace instance - global variables are just the simplest and more straightforward thing to do, and easier to write in this example.

Tnx for help, and I also dont understand if I run gunicorn with 2 workers on dual-core cpu. That means 2 workers are analogous as 2 processes that will run a "main" fast-api process with an event loop, and another subprocess with "initialize_subprocess()" invoked. So I have 2 processes, and each of them have its own subprocess ? If that is true, that means I have to load model 2 times in two workers. Theoretically what can happen is one worker gets updated model and serves it, and another is still at the old model version, so 2 (same) requests can give different results ?

Continuing on my previous comment, --preload (Load application code before the worker processes are forked.) Is it possible to load model trough preload worker, and update model only in that "preload space" ?
